# Why use "accepts_nested_attributes_for" when you can already save through the parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When should I use "accepts_nested_attributes_for"?  In the example below, I can do a successful "user.microposts.create" without needing "accepts_nested_attributes_for" in the User model.

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`accepts_nested_attributes_for` is just a shortcut. It defines a dynamic attribute `{field_name}_attributes` so that if you have a form you can include nested attributes and have it automatically assign them to an association. Like so :

```
form_for :object do |f|
  f.text_field :attr1
  f.text_field :attr2
  f.fields_for :association_attributes do |g|
    g.text_field :nested1
    g.text_field :nested2
  end
end
```

This posts with parameters `{object: {attr1: val, attr2: val, association_attributes: {nested1: val, nested2: val}}` and adding  `accepts_nested_attributes_for :association` to your class makes the whole thing work without any extra code.

Comment: So using your form, but with my example, and without "accepts_nested_attributes_for", I'd have to call params twice ([:object] and [:object][:association]) in the controller?

Comment: well, without `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and with that form, you'd get an error "Undefined method association_attributes= for object object". In order to make it work you'd need to make the object from `params[:object].except(:association_attributes)` then make the association from `object.associations.new(params[:object][:association_attributes])`.

Comment: You don't have to do :association_attributes, just `:association` with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your model will automatically make the attributes called `association_attributes`.

Comment: That's true, you don't need `association_attributes` in the call to `accepts_nested_attribute_for`, but you do need it in the form.